# Fetch Join with select statement in JPAQuery

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I have two entities: BlogArticle and BlogTag

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class BlogArticle {
    private UUID id;
    private String title;

    // other fields...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles")
    private List<BlogTag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class BlogTag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Builder.Default
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<BlogArticle> articles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I fetch them with a JPAQuery like so:

```java
        Tuple tuple = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager)
                .from(qBlogArticle)
                .innerJoin(qBlogArticle.tags)
                .fetchJoin()
                .where(qBlogArticle.slug.eq(slug))
                .fetchOne();
```

It works, but when I add a `.select(qBlogArticle.title, qBlogArticle.tags`, it throws an error saying "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list"

How can select only the fields I want, and fetch join tags (so they can be fetched in one query)?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate only allows FETCH JOINS if the owner of the fetch association is projected in the select clause. so the way to make it work would be to add qBlogArticle to the select .select(qBlogArticle, qBlogArticle.title, qBlogArticle.tags)

Comment: The generated SQL query still fetches other fields, and it throws a "query did not return a unique result" error?